# "No files available for download"

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, ftp

There is a strange problem with Netbeans. I'm trying to create new project with remote resources but when I enter all FTP and project information, Netbeans says

> No files available for download. Try to check Passive mode in the
>   remote configuration

Although I tried the passive mode, it isn't the problem. There are many folders and files and I can see them via FTP client or I can create the project with same method on another Netbeans which is running another computer.

Both of them has Netbeans 7.0, both of them running Windows 7 and both of them using same internet connection!

There are no firewall or similar protection by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For **Netbeans 7.3**, with **Windows 7**, using **JDK 7**

Open CMD as Administrator and run the following:

```
netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable
```

To open CMD as Administrator in Windows 7:

1. Select Start
2. In the "Search programs and files" box
3. Enter "CMD"
4. Find the result above and right click on it
5. Select "Run as Administrator" from the context menu

*I found this after some digging via Mansiemans shared link. Some of the commands on that thread, did not work, so I am sharing the one that did work.*

Comment: It's been 6 years since I've asked this and no idea what was the actual problem but  am picking this as right answer since it has the most upvotes :)

Answer (score 2):

```
Initial Directory: "/"
Port: "21"
Set Passive mode on
```

Comment: Worked for me too. In two cases with the same hosting provider, as long as the initial directory is set to root it works.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to uninstall Java or re-install NetBeans. Just change the Java version used by Netbeans.

1. Edit file: `<netbeans dir>\etc\netbeans.conf`
2. Change this line: `netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jre6"`

Comment: NetBeans 7.4 Doesn't allow to use Java 6 :(

Answer (score 2):

I did not uninstall any thing.
I got jdk 1.6 folder from another computer and copied it to my computer in java installation directory.
Then I edited the \etc\netbeans.conf.
Changed this line: netbeans_jdkhome="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0"

jre6 was not working.
I did this in passive mode.

Comment: Actually, for me, changing from 64 bit jre7 to 32 bit jre6 fixed my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall java 7 and java se 7 development and install the last java 6 version http://www.java.com/en/download/inc/windows_new_xpi.jsp

Answer (score 1):

upload directory in connector was automatically named as the project, making the dir on server that the connector will test: `ftp://mysite.foo/mysite/mysite` **instead of** `ftp://mysite.foo/mysite/`

**clearing "upload directory" field worked for me**

Answer (score 0):

This [page](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/remote-hosting-and-ftp-account.html) has a suggestion that worked for me. Apparently, Windows 7 / Vista firewall blocks certain FTP operations. When I turn off my Vista firewall, Netbeans does its thing.

Answer (score 0):

If passive mode fails to get files then connect by Turning off your Firewall. In my case it worked. Then you can create a Rule in Firewall to allow netbeans.

Comment: There is no firewall in place, OP says.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because your user account on the FTP server is configured to change to an initial directory upon connection.

Example: The Netbeans path is showing ftp://example.com/www/example.com (combining your provided host, initial directory and upload directory settings). However, your FTP user account is configured to initially connect to /www as the FTP root. Despite what Netbeans is telling you, you are actually connecting to ftp://example.com/www/www/example.com because, upon connection, the FTP server has changed the directory to www for your user account.

In which case, even though Netbeans is showing the correct path in the project wizard and in the console, you may not actually be connecting to the path in your Netbeans settings.

You can usually check if this is the case easily if you have a hosting account control panel with an FTP settings page. Your host may, however, not allow you to change the FTP root for security reasons (or perhaps you just shouldn't).

If you cannot change the FTP user root, or would prefer not to, then (in the e.g. above) you will have to make sure the Netbeans FTP path is ftp://example.com/example.com missing out the "www" directory (even though that is actually part of the correct path) because the FTP server will automatically change to this as the FTP root.

The above approach fixed this problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Set the initial directory chmod to 777.